# Write exponent as a superscript in R

Tags: r, exponent, superscript

I have created the following function in R

```
 fchange<-function(n) {
 if(n>=10|n<1){
  not1 <- format(n, scientific = TRUE)
  not1 <- sub("e", "*10^", not1)
  not1 <- sub("\\+0?", "", not1)
  not1 <- sub("-0?", "-", not1)
  return(not1)
  }}
```

This takes a value and returns a character- Thus 100 is  10^2. Is there a way to remove the caret and convert the exponent into a superscript

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing how you want to output the return value. Will this be in a plot, a markdown document, a file (what kind of file?), printing to the R console, a shiny app, ...? The operating system could also be relevant.

Comment: What for? Are you doing a plot and want them to appear with superscript instead of exponent?

Comment: See [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) for using superscripts in plots.

Comment: It is for a shiny App.